Vari-Bright in Ubuntu 24.04
I believe AMD Vari Bright is affecting the gamma of my display, and I want to turn it off, but I am not sure exactly how I can do this.
CPU/GPU: Ryzen 7 7840U w/ Radeon 780M

This was introduced in Linux 6.9 with this patch.
To turn off Vari-Bright, use one of these methods:

Adding amdgpu.abmlevel=0 to the kernel command line to disable ABM value changes entirely.

Using --block-action=amdgpu_panel_power in the power-profiles-daemon ExecStart command to prevent the Power Profiles Daemon from changing ABM values.


Source from Arch Linux forum

Thanks! This worked!
